# Replace residue numbers in pdb with given residue numbers list

Tags: python, biopython, pdb, pdb-files

I have renumbered residue numbers list as new_residues=[18,19,20,21,22,34,35,36,37.... 130,131,132] and I would like to change my pdb residue numbers with this list. Do you have any idea to re-numbering ?

...

```
w=PDBIO()
            structure=p.get_structure(" ", pdbfile)
            for model in structure:
                    for chain in model:
                            chain_ID=model[chainID]
                            for residue in chain_ID:
                            #for i in range(len(residue.id)):
                                            #resID=new_resnums[i]
                                    residue.id=(" ",new_resnums[residue.id[1]], " ")
            w.set_structure(structure)
            w.save(pdbfile + "-new.pdb")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you are overwriting all the information about the residue, also the info about the amino acid in the particular position.

Let's increment all ids in our file by 200, loop through the `model`s and `structures` and then use `get_residues()` in combination with `enumerate` to get all the residues and an index.

The residue.id is stored in a `list` and only the id is changed. This `list` is then converted back to a `tuple` and written in place of the original id.

```
from Bio import PDB

pdb_io = PDB.PDBIO()
pdb_parser = PDB.PDBParser()
pdbfile = '1ubq.pdb'
structure = pdb_parser.get_structure(" ", pdbfile)

new_resnums = [i + 200 for i in range(135)]

for model in structure:
    for chain in model:
        for i, residue in enumerate(chain.get_residues()):
            res_id = list(residue.id)
            res_id[1] = new_resnums[i]
            residue.id = tuple(res_id)

pdb_io.set_structure(structure)
pdb_io.save(pdbfile + "-new.pdb")
```